# Namespaced Vuex module getter registers as number instead of the module name

Tags: vue.js, module, namespaces, vuex, getter

I have Vue 2.5.16 and Vuex 3.0.1, both are freshly installed using vue-cli 3.0.0-rc.3

I have some namespaced Vuex modules, like this:

```
// src/store/brand.js
export default {
    getters: {
        value1 (state) {
            return state.value1
        }

        value2 (state) {
            return state.value2
        }
    },

    namespaced: true,

    state: {
        value1: 1,
        value2: 2
    }
}
```

My modules are registered in a central script:

```
// src/store/index.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

import brand from './brand'
import shared from './shared'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
    modules: [
        brand,
        shared
    ]
})
```

Unless I'm gravely mistaken, Vuex module [getters are supposed to be namespaced using the module name](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#namespacing), so I should be able to use `$store.getters['brand/value1]`, but for some reason I only have `$store.getters['0/value1']`.

This is confirmed by the Vue devtool, so for some reason the module is registered by its **index number** instead of its name.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change your modules definition from an array to an object.

From:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: [
    brand,
    shared
  ]
})
```

To:

```
  export default new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
      brand,
      shared
    }
  })
```

Comment: You're so right, thanks! :) (I'll accept your answer in 7 minutes, S.O. won't let me do this sooner.)